# Multi-device hybrid apps: Use Xcode6 and iOS8 SDK

Tags: ios, xcode, visual-studio-cordova

we want to use the new Xcode6 and iOS8 SDK to build our mda apps. I installed the sdk on the mac, but i cannot build at the moment using the new sdk, because it seems like the new devices and emulators are not displayed in Visual Studio. It is also not possible to choose an old device, because it says that it cannot find the emulator I've specified (I think they renamed the emulator devices). I switched back now to Xcode 5.1.1, but we would really want to use the new sdk to get the new features.

Do you have any plans when we can use the new Xcode?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an update made today to `vs-mda-remote` which should add in support for XCode6. Please make sure you get the latest version by running `sudo npm install -g vs-mda-remote --user=$USER` from your machine. This should get your build to pass. If you run into further issues, please email vscordovatools@microsoft.com to discuss further.

There was a [plugins release](http://cordova.apache.org/news/2014/09/22/plugins-release.html) for September recently. If any of your current plugins seem to be flaky, you may want to consider updating them manually by editing the config.xml file.